# Getting "Net::HTTPError: Forbidden (403)"

Tags: google-api, google-contacts-api

While syncing contacts (fetching contacts from Google or updating a contact from Google), I am getting `Net::HTTPError: Forbidden (403)`.

Would like to know in which cases this exception can arise. Any url that explains this error would help us to debug this issue and analyze different scenarios in which this error can be raised.

Overview of our application's google integration:

1. Our application is built on Ruby on Rails (3.2.18).
2. We are using `google-contacts` gem (https://github.com/varunlalan/google-contacts) for syncing contacts.
3. We authenticate user using `omniauth-google-oauth2` gem (https://github.com/zquestz/omniauth-google-oauth2).
4. OAuth 2 scopes include - `userinfo.email, userinfo.profile, https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/`

Any help or inputs would be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: "While syncing contacts" How long was it running when you got this error?

Comment: @DaImTo Does this error depend on running time? Not sure if that is the case. It seems to be request limit issue from Google's side.